# Reloading a specific element with ajax

Tags: php, html, ajax, wordpress

I was working at a wordpress website. I use a plugin named my cred so any user has a points balance. It is displayed on everypage. The problem is that when the user spends points, the balance dosen't change unless the user reload the page and it's annoyng. I decided to use AJAX to reload the element every 2 seconds (is that even the best idea ?)

I browsed stackoverflow and i found answers at how to reload a div element with AJAX but i dont understand at all.

```html
<div id="balance" align="right"
     <strong><strong></strong>

        <?php if (  is_user_logged_in() ) {

        echo '<strong>Balance: </strong>'.do_shortcode( '[mycred_my_balance wrapper=0 title_el="" balance_el=""]', $ignore_html = false ).'♥'.'';

        echo '<a href="cumpara-sau-castiga"
>
</a>';}




?>
```

All i want is the best way to reload it when user spends points without making pressure on the server. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

//add this code on your functions.php

```
add_action( 'init', 'my_script_enqueuer' );
function my_script_enqueuer() {
   wp_localize_script( 'reloadVars', 'custom_vars', array( 'ajaxurl' => admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' )));
}

add_action("wp_ajax_reload_balance", "reload_balance");
add_action("wp_ajax_nopriv_reload_balance", "reload_balance");
function reload_balance() {
    $balance = "";
    if (  is_user_logged_in() ) {
        $balance .= '<strong>Balance: </strong>'.do_shortcode( '[mycred_my_balance wrapper=0 title_el="" balance_el=""]', $ignore_html = false ).'♥'.'';
        $balance .= '<a href="cumpara-sau-castiga"></a>';
    }
    echo $balance;
    wp_die();
}


//Add this code either on your js file or in footer.php
<script>
setInterval(function(){
 jQuery.ajax({
   type : "post",
   url : ajaxurl,
   data : {action: "reload_balance"},
   success: function(response) {
      jQuery("#balance").html(response);
   }
 });
}, 3000);
```

Comment: <div id="balance" align="right">
     <strong></strong>
        <?php if (  is_user_logged_in() ) {
        echo '<strong>Balance: </strong>'.do_shortcode( '[mycred_my_balance wrapper=0 title_el="" balance_el=""]', $ignore_html = false ).'♥'.'';
        echo '<a href="cumpara-sau-castiga"></a>';
    } ?>
</div>

Comment: @root can you tell me in detail if it is showing any error?

Comment: @root can you also tell me that is it showing the balance on first time when the page loads?

Comment: when the page loads the balance is like this> Balance: 955,455 ♥. After spending points (lets suppose 10) it does not change to Balance: 955,445 ♥ without a refresh. And no there is no error displayed.

Comment: ok can you share the url where it is deployed so that i can check and let you know as this is working on my side.

Comment: https://matrimoniale.org - just make an account and you will get 100 points. you can spend by commenting on some user activity

Comment: @root i am not getting this code where you added this.

//Add this code either on your js file or in footer.php
<script>
setTimeout(function(){
 jQuery.ajax({
   type : "post",
   url : custom_vars.ajaxurl,
   data : {action: "reload_balance"},
   success: function(response) {
      jQuery("#balance").html(response);
   }
 });
}, 3000);

Comment: i increased your balance...i removed the code, i added it back now

Comment: @root use this "ajaxurl" instead of "custom_vars.ajaxurl"

Comment: as it is not working due to this  is not added on your functions.php file

add_action( 'init', 'my_script_enqueuer' );
function my_script_enqueuer() {
   wp_localize_script( 'reloadVars', 'custom_vars', array( 'ajaxurl' => admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' )));
}

Comment: i did as you said...now it acts stange - check

Comment: ok great now it is working but needs some styling changes so let me share you the code.
update this on your functions.php file
add_action("wp_ajax_reload_balance", "reload_balance");
add_action("wp_ajax_nopriv_reload_balance", "reload_balance");
function reload_balance() {
    $balance = "";
    if (  is_user_logged_in() ) {
         $balance .= '<strong>Balance: </strong>'.do_shortcode( '[mycred_my_balance wrapper=0 title_el="" balance_el=""]', $ignore_html = false ).'♥'.'';
        $balance .= '<a href="cumpara-sau-castiga"></a>';
    }
    echo $balance;
    wp_die();
}

Comment: I updated the function on main answer check and update once.

Comment: i added the styled version but still after commenting the number do not change

Comment: on my side it is changing the amount every 3 seconds.

Comment: @root sorry my mistake we need to use "setInterval" instead of "setTimeout"

Comment: Sir, it works. God bless you. Only 1 question ? does it slow down the server if there are many users spending points ?

Comment: not effect much on server as we are not doing any process on the files.
And if it is working so can you mark my answer as correct one?
Thank you

Comment: we are just rendering the html so it will not effect to the server.